# pytorch model not updating

Tags: python, pytorch, training-data

I put my training code below. I am using  torch.optim.SGD as optimizer. I thought optimizer.step() would be doing the update but the model accuracy seems to stay the same. My friend said he didn't use the optimizer.step() and his works fine.
I tried taking it out, still the same result. What can I be doing wrong? 
I don't think there's a problem with the accuracy calculation.

```
class FNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128*256, 1024) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 2)

    def forward(self, X): 
        X = F.relu(self.fc1(X))
        X = F.relu(self.fc2(X))
        X = self.fc3(X)
        return F.softmax(X, dim=1)



def main():

    learning_rate = 0.01
    model = FNet()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=5e-04) # you can play with momentum and weight_decay parameters as well
    accs = [0,]

    for epoch in range(max_epoch):

        train(epoch, model, optimizer, train_batch)

        acc = test(model, val_batch)
        accs.append(acc)


def train(epoch, model, optimizer, trainloader):
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    for batch_idx, (data, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):

        outputs = model(data)
        loss = F.nll_loss(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()


def test(model, testloader):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    model.eval()

    for batch_idx, (data, labels) in enumerate(testloader):

            outputs = model(data.view(-1,128*256))

            for sample_idx,output in enumerate(outputs):

                if torch.argmax(output) == labels[sample_idx]:
                    correct = correct + 1
                total = total + 1

    accuracy = correct/total
    return accuracy
```

Comment: Giving a small snippet of code doesn't help. Relevant info is missing like, have you passed the model parameters to the optimizer? Optimizer needs to know what parameters to update.

Comment: i added the rest of the running code.

Comment: Did you observe the loss values, does it decrease?

Comment: loss values are all over the place, sometimes they decrease sometimes they go back up. im not sure what is happening

Comment: Can you use the optimizer without setting momentum and weight decay and check?

Comment: loss still was rising and falling without a pattern

Comment: Looks like your test loop has an indentation issue? Did you try fixing that?

Comment: does it? where?!?! you might have just saved my life

Answer (score 1):

I think this line should be under your for loop
`optimizer.zero_grad()`. You need to clear the parameter gradients after each loop.

try this

```
def train(epoch, model, optimizer, trainloader):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(data)
        loss = F.nll_loss(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: this didnt affect anything

Comment: Even if it doesn't affect, you must call zero_grad at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [log_softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html?highlight=log_softmax#torch.nn.functional.log_softmax) instead of `softmax` in the last line of your model.

```
def forward(self, X): 
    X = F.relu(self.fc1(X))
    X = F.relu(self.fc2(X))
    X = self.fc3(X)
    return F.log_softmax(X, dim=1) # => use `log_softmax` instead.
```

The [NLLLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss) requires the input to be log-probabilities. The documentation says:

> The input given through a forward call is expected to contain log-probabilities of each class.

---

Also, use `optimizer.zero_grad()` inside the for loop as mentioned in [@Dishin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61854795/5352399).

Comment: fixed the zero grad, changed it to log_softmax, now the loss stays almost the same and accuracy is still not changing